# Run Target as Simulator is missing on the Xcode15

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode15

### Can not select `Run Destination` on Xcode 15.1/15.2 for Simulators

I have been using Xcode15.1 and recently updated to Xcode15.2. For a few days, I have been switching back and forth from both versions as needed for different projects.

Now, after restarting today, I'm unable to choose any simulator for target. There is enough disk-space, and tried downloading new version of simulator as well. Restarted the MacBook a couple of times.

Any suggestions?

[image: Xcode-run-target-simulator-missing]

Upon tapping Unable to update Index
`Failed to retrieve available downloads for this version of Xcode.` error shows up.

[image: Unable to update Index]

Details:

```
Failed to retrieve available downloads for this version of Xcode.
Domain: DVTDownloadableErrorDomain
Code: -1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-01-30 21:39:41 +0000";
}
--
Unable to deserialize downloadables index request data.
Domain: DVTDownloadableErrorDomain
Code: 6
User Info: {
    URL = "https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index2.dvtdownloadableindex";
}
--
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 3840
Failure Reason: The data is not in the correct format.
User Info: {
    NSDebugDescription = "Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.2.1 (Build 23C71)
Xcode 15.2 (22503) (Build 15C500b)
Timestamp: 2024-01-30T13:39:41-08:00
```

### Can not select `Run Destination` on Xcode 15.1/15.2 for Simulators

I have been using Xcode15.1 and recently updated to Xcode15.2. For a few days, I have been switching back and forth from both versions as needed for different projects.

Now, after restarting today, I'm unable to choose any simulator for target. There is enough disk-space, and tried downloading new version of simulator as well. Restarted the MacBook a couple of times.

Any suggestions?

[image: Xcode-run-target-simulator-missing]

Upon tapping Unable to update Index
`Failed to retrieve available downloads for this version of Xcode.` error shows up.

[image: Unable to update Index]

Details:

```
Failed to retrieve available downloads for this version of Xcode.
Domain: DVTDownloadableErrorDomain
Code: -1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-01-30 21:39:41 +0000";
}
--
Unable to deserialize downloadables index request data.
Domain: DVTDownloadableErrorDomain
Code: 6
User Info: {
    URL = "https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index2.dvtdownloadableindex";
}
--
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 3840
Failure Reason: The data is not in the correct format.
User Info: {
    NSDebugDescription = "Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.2.1 (Build 23C71)
Xcode 15.2 (22503) (Build 15C500b)
Timestamp: 2024-01-30T13:39:41-08:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the impression that the error is coming from Apple's servers. I'm having the same problem myself. The https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/index2.dvtdownloadableindex page doesn't return anything.

Comment: Me too! I've tried the new Xcode 15 Beta, and same issue. I think this is an "Apple problem".

Comment: Facing the same issue

Comment: I am having the same issue/error as well. Started a new gig yesterday, new computer, so I can't get my environment working. I went to another computer I had Xcode on, but it had updated to 15.2 and it's hosed as well. Doh!

Comment: having problems too with recent updates

Comment: I got it working after deleting the existing simulators and download it again for Xcode15.1.

Also did set both simulator architecture to allow:  https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730022

Comment: Looks like it's fixed on the server side now. The options to download are back, and that error no longer occurs.